# Using the colorbox for pop-up immediately open (jQuery - Magento)

Tags: magento, colorbox

I'm using Jquery colorbox to implement a popup windows. This pop-up is immediately open and it's working. But for the first loading page, just the first loading, the pop-up can't load the content.
[image: My screen]

```
jQuery(document).ready(function defaultPopup(){

    var direct = '<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('popup')->toHtml(); ?>'
    if(direct){
        jQuery('#popup_home').colorbox({open:true,html:direct,overlayClose:false});
        return false;
    }
});
<div id="popup_home"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape special characters (`<>`) in your string.

For the web browser the content of your `direct` variable is an HTML tag without content.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function defaultPopup(){
var direct = '<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\'cms/block\')->setBlockId(\'popup\')->toHtml(); ?>'
direct = $('<div/>').text(direct).text() // escaping characters in the initial string
if(direct){
    jQuery('#popup_home').colorbox({open:true,html:direct,overlayClose:false});
    return false;
}
});
<div id="popup_home"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but .text(direct) it load everything in cms block[html form]. Like a link it load [<a href="" ..></a>]

Comment: I updated the solution, check it, please. I updated the characters escaping (previous version returned object instead of string), besides I manually escaped single quotes in the initial string - this had to be done on the server when you generated the string `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('popup')->toHtml(); ?>`